# Как правильно перенести сайт на Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

У меня есть сайт на домене, скажем http://magazin.ru . Мне нужно перенести весь сайт в подпапку http://magazin.ru/shop . Все файлы я закинул, но внутренние ссылки работают криво и теперь не открывается главная страница сайта. Что ещё нужно поменять? Подозреваю, что в БД нужно править ссылки. Может кто сталкивался с подобным ? Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно поправить параметр "Папка сайта" в настройках вашего сайта. Для сайта с идентификатором s1 в админке это здесь: `/bitrix/admin/site_edit.php?LID=s1&lang=ru`

И, если никаких дополнительных изменений в шаблонах не делали, всё должно спокойно заработать. В частности, внутренние ссылки и главная точно оттуда берутся.

Answer (score 0):

А Вы файлы просто скопировали?
Я бы советовал сделать бэк-ап битрикса через внутренюю утилиту, а потом распаковать в нужной папке. При распаковке будут параметры, которые Вам помогут.

Comment: Просто создал папку и перенес все файлы туда, да.

Comment: Битрикс - вредный - делайте через бэкапирование и восстановление бэкапа